# How to give parameter name for function in function?

Tags: python

I need choose which parameter i use for function in function.

For example:

```
def some(key, gey, mey):
    return 0


def any(parameter_name, parameter_value):
    some(parameter_name=parameter_value)


any(mey, "May")
```

`any(mey, "May")` should equel `some(mey="May")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `**kwargs` syntax. It will filter `attribute` by `attribute_value`.

```py
def get_object_id(attribute: str, attribute_value):
    MyModel.objects.get(**{attribute: attribute_value})
```